# Go back without rerendering the parent page Maui Blazor mobile app

Tags: c#, maui, maui-blazor

I am developing a mobile app using Maui and Blazor. In regular Maui apps, pages can be registered with different lifecycles such as singleton or transient.

This provides some cool benefits, such as avoiding the need to reload or rerender data on the page. For example, if there is a page with list of elements and open a detail page for an element, the list page can be registered as a singleton and the details page as transient. This allows when navigate back, the parent page remains in the same state, such as scrolled down to a specific position.

How is it possible to manage this with Maui Blazor mobile app?

I was thinking to use a full page dialog, only if there is no other solution for this.

Comment: [Preserve Blazor state / in memory container service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=webassembly#in-memory-state-container-service-wasm) might be helpful.

Comment: As I understand it is about store a property value in memory, which I have solved similar way as in the article. It works but when I open the details page of an item, when navigate back to the list page due its re rendering it does not keep the position of the scroll as i left it goes always to the top.

Comment: Well It's a Blazor virtualize component to show list of elements, something like this.

<Virtualize Context="row" ItemsProvider="@GetRows">
    ...
</Virtualize>

But its the same as any page from parent to child when back the parent is re-rendered so all the data and reloaded and the scroll position is lost. Which is normal but in regular Maui it can be solved with adding page's lifetime.

Comment: For Blazor, there is only one way is state management as ToolmakerSteve said that.
  You can refer to this article: [Prevent refreshing the UI after an event in Blazor](https://www.meziantou.net/prevent-refreshing-the-ui-after-an-event-in-blazor.htm).